# How to read keyless querystring in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, query-string

What is replacement in .NET Core for keyless query string parameters?

In asp.net, the syntax was `Request.QueryString[ null ]`, however .NET Core throws null exception for this, not allowing you to pass in `null` for the key name.

For example, I need to support a url in this format:

`http://localhost:54301/RBLeCORS.ashx?{Command:CalcEngineStatus}`

However, in addition to this, I need to be able to handle a command posted with `$.ajax()` calls from javascript where the data is posted instead of put on the querystring.

Where the keyless (I see comments want to call it valueless, which is appropriate for .NET Core I guess, but I saw them called keyless for asp.net b/c you access with the `null` key) value is a json object that can have more than just this simple example I gave.

Update: Here is my current code I did as workaround.

```
        string queryData = null;
        if (context.Request.Query.Count == 1 )
        {
            var firstKey = context.Request.Query.Keys.ElementAt(0);
            var firstValue = context.Request.Query[firstKey];

            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( firstValue ) )
            {
                queryData = firstKey;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by keyless?

Comment: Can you show an example of a uri you're trying to parse?

Comment: If you're just expecting a JSON command or other parseable, why not just convert it to string so you can parse it (`var command = Request.HasValue ? Request.QueryString.Value.Substring(1) : "{}";`)

Comment: @JasonW I need to support both information passed on QueryString and also data posted in a form.  Will test your method of Request.HasValue, but it looks cleaner than my workaround I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://code-examples.net/en/q/61bec) I noticed this:

> You can use null as the key for the NameValueCollection and it will
>   give you a comma-delimited list of parameter names that don't have
>   values.
>
> For http://example.com?bar=3&foo you would use
>   `Request.QueryString[null]` and it would retrieve foo.

So, in dotnet core, this won't work.

`Request` contains a property called `Query` which is of type `IQueryCollection`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iquerycollection?view=aspnetcore-2.1

With this, you can use the `Item[String]` to get an item by a known key, as you know.

`Keys` contains a list of all keys present in the query collection.

What I think you want, is to get all the values, irrespective of their keys?

You could use:

```
var values = Request.Query.ToList ()
    .SelectMany (x => x.Value);
```

`values` will be a list of values passed in to the query string:

> ?key1=val1&key2=val2

Would return

- val1
- val2

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this right now looking for one key and determining what it is and then if the associated value is null, I assume it is 'the same thing I processed' in asp.net and proceed.  Will see if anyone posts anything, otherwise I'll show my sample code.

Comment: Show it anyway, we might stand a better chance of answering the question!

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to use a query string like this as "keyless":

```
{pathToRoute}?item1&item2
```

Then you can use `ContainsKey` to check if a parameter is passed:

```
Request.Query.ContainsKey("item1") // true
```

If you want to get a list of all of these commands from a query string:

```
string[] commands = Request.Query
    .Where(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value))
    .Select(m => m.Key).ToArray();
```

For `?{Command:CalcEngineStatus}&{Command:Command2}`, this would return a string[] of `{Command:CalcEngineStatus}` and `{Command:Command2}`.

Comment: I would consider those "valueless", not "keyless".

Comment: I agree that valueless is more appropriate :)

Comment: I see your point for valueless vs keyless, but also, I can check for a specific key because it is just a json string/package that is passed to the web service.

Comment: Added additional code to load a list of these commands based on example you added to OP...hopefully this might help.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core I would use `Request.QueryString` (not `Query`) and you would get the value you are looking, though with an `?` in the beginning. For more details, see https://developer.azurewebsites.net/aspnet-core-request-property-values?something#querystring